# What does 付き合わされる身になって mean?

Tags: translation

I've come across two lines in some dialogue that used 付き合わされる身になって as follows:

1. 悪ふざけに付き合わされる身になってよ
2. 付き合わされる身になって欲しいわ

So far, I've only been able to find that 身になって is used to ask someone to put themselves in the speaker's shoes. I'm unsure on the 付き合わされる part, but would it be wrong to guess that the two lines above meaning the following?

1. Put yourself in my shoes, having been forced to play along with this prank.
2. I'd like you to put yourself in my shoes to see how I've been forced to play along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「悪{わる}ふざけに付{つ}き合{あ}わされる身{み}になってよ。」
>
> 「付き合わされる身になって欲しいわ。」

This is a surprisingly tough one if literal translation is what one is after because even though 「身になる」 is a set phrase, 「身」 is a noun and therefore, one can grammatically insert the relative clause 「（悪ふざけに）付き合わされる」 to modify it in Japanese.  This sentence structure works with no problems in that language.

In English, however, how do you modify the noun "shoes" in the expression "to put yourself in someone's shoes" by using a relative clause without creating any grammatical clumsiness?  Perhaps English-speakers would know how, but I do not.

All I can say for sure is that from your TL attempts,  you clearly seem to know what these sentences mean.  As long as you know that 「付き合わされる」 is in the **causative passive-voice** form ("to be forced to play along"), actual translations can come in different forms.

Comment: Thanks for putting the time in to respond! I thought it was just my lack of ability to translate these lines properly since I couldn't phrase them in English without awkwardness in the sentence.

Comment: I don't think your first rendering is that clumsy depending on where it comes in a dialogue. You could also try something a little more flexible like "Imagine being forced to [play along with a prank.]"